# Update table with values of another table (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms, common-table-expression

I'm trying to update an table with data from another table (using PostgreSQL). My table is something like:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|   id_location     |   user_location   |   social_sec_number   |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|   00000000001     |   Jason (null)    |   812.539.037         |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|   00000000002     |   Jennifer (null) |   066.307.382         |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|   00000000003     |   Albert (null)   |   560.732.535         |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

And I want Into this:

```
+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
|   id_location     |   user_location           |   social_sec_number   |
+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
|   00000000001     |   Jason (812.539.037)     |   812.539.037         |
+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
|   00000000002     |   Jennifer (066.307.382)  |   066.307.382         |
+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
|   00000000003     |   Albert (560.732.535)    |   560.732.535         |
+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Columns `id_location` and `user_location` are in the same table `TableLocation`, but `social_sec_number` are in another table.

My code trying update them (*this code does not reflect what was shown in the examples of tables*):

```
WITH tb_cpf
AS (
    SELECT doc.nr_documento_identificacao
    FROM core.tb_usuario_localizacao ul
    INNER JOIN core.tb_localizacao l ON ul.id_localizacao = l.id_localizacao
    INNER JOIN client.tb_pess_doc_identificacao doc ON ul.id_usuario = doc.id_pessoa
    WHERE l.ds_localizacao ilike '%(null)%'
        AND doc.cd_tp_documento_identificacao = 'CPF'
    )
UPDATE core.tb_localizacao AS l
SET l.ds_localizacao = REPLACE(l.ds_localizacao, '(null)', tb_cpf)
WHERE l.id_localizacao IN (
        SELECT l.id_localizacao
        FROM core.tb_usuario_localizacao ul
        INNER JOIN core.tb_localizacao l ON ul.id_localizacao = l.id_localizacao
        INNER JOIN client.tb_pess_doc_identificacao doc ON ul.id_usuario = doc.id_pessoa
        WHERE l.ds_localizacao ilike '%(null)%'
            AND doc.cd_tp_documento_identificacao = 'CPF'
        )
    AND tb_pess_doc_identificacao.id_pessoa = tb_usuario_localizacao.id_usuario
    AND tb_usuario_localizacao.id_localizacao = tb_localizacao.id_localizacao;
```

And I receive this ugly error:

```
ERROR: column "tb_cpf" does not exist
LINE 11: ... of l.ds_localizacao = REPLACE (l.ds_localization, '(null)', tb_cpf) 
                                                                            ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: column "tb_cpf" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 433
```

That way, it is possible that each record with "null" is replaced by social security (for example) on every table?

Answer (score 0):

The `tb_cpf` from the CTE works like any other relation in your main `UPDATE` statement. You are missing a column identifier, so if you add `.nr_documento_identificacao` to `tb_cpf` then the update should work:

```
WITH tp_cpf AS (
  ...
)
UPDATE core.tb_localizacao AS l
SET l.ds_localizacao = REPLACE(l.ds_localizacao, 'null', tb_cpf.nr_documento_identificacao)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.. you say something like: `tb_cpf.nr_documento_identificacao`? Or another alias from `SELECT doc.nr_documento_identificacao`?

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding `with` clause usage. Think of it like a view or like a subquery. It works exactly like a memory table. You have to expose all columns you're gonna use.

But, why are you complicating it so much? Why don't you do something as simple as this?

```
update mytable m1

set m1.mycolumn = replace(  m1.mycolumn, 
                            '(null)', 
                            (
                            select mycolumn2 
                            from mytable2 m2 
                            where m2.id = m1.id
                            ) 
                        )

where m1.mycolumn like '%(null)'
```

Or, if you really want to use `with` (for performance issues):

```
with t1 as
(select t.id,
        t.mycolumn
   from mytable
)

update mytable2 t2
   set t2.mycolumn = replace (t2.mycolumn, '(null)', t1.mycolumn)
 where t2.id = t1.id
   and t2.mycolumn like '%(null)'
```